# Package installation issues with R 3.1.0

Tags: r

My Fedora system (Fedora 20, all up to date) has just had R updated to version 3.1.0.  Since then, I've had issues installing multiple packages.  glmnet failed previously, and now I'm having trouble with treemap.  More specifically, I get an error during treemap installation that httpuv has zero exit status.

I never had issues with the previous version of R.  Any reason this version should have such problems??

Comment: Could you paste some code/errors? I have this problem often on servers and I have some work arounds, but without seeing the details of the errors I can't be certain my solution will work for you. If you can, please maximize the verbosity of the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be many causes to do with your OS, version, permissions, other installed packages/software, etc, etc. Without seeing the full error message it's hard to know.

One possibility specific to `httpuv` is root privileges. I've noticed a few threads on various forums when searching for installation errors with this package and Linux, many of them mentioning root v. non-root issues. In another case, `libuv` needed to be upgraded.

I encounter package installation problems daily and I have some more general work-arounds as well. Hopefully one of these will solve your problem.

- Install the package from source

`download.file(url="http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/httpuv_1.3.0.tar.gz", destfile = "httpuv.tar.gz")`

`install.packages("httpuv.tar.gz", type = "source", repos = NULL)`

- Install using `devtools` via `GitHub` if the package supports it
- Install `RTools` and re-try your package installation
- Install an older version of the package

If those above do not work, then I dig deeper by referring to advice given to me by a VP of IT in my company. These comments were made in reference to frequent package installation problems I encountered when switching from `Windows` to `Solaris`:

> There are two types of install/make problems. Missing .h files
> and/or missing .so/.a libs. The reason for these are multiple:
>
> 1.- the package that delivers these is not installed. This means that those files cannot be found anywhere in the /usr tree. Solution is
> install right package, make sure the files are there
>
> 2.- the includes are not found by the install configurator. This means some environment variable or install option is not properly set (this
> is our case for RODBC). Figuring out which variable to set is
> challenging without looking at the package documentation [fortunately, documentation is not hard to find!]
>
> 3.- the libs are not in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, easy to fix.
>
> 4.- There is a deeper compile/link error, meaning the package is not compatible with the rest of the sw, or has not been properly ported.

Comment: It was httpuv.  I installed it from source as root, and then treemap installed fine.  Thank you!!